# Do stress-protection deodorants work better for stress sweat?

Tags: physiology

Many deodorant manufacturers claim that they have products specifically targeted to prevent stress sweating, or "emotional sweating" as I have seen. Some examples come from [Nivea](http://www.nivea.com.au/products/deodorant/stress-protect/stress-protect-women-roll-on) and [Vichy](http://www.en.vichy.ca/Deodorant/Lip-protection/Stress-Resist-Anti-perspirant-Intensive-Treatment-%E2%80%93-Excessive-perspiration-p915.aspx).

> Did you know that we sweat differently when we are under stress? Our body reacts by producing more sweat, triggering stronger odour than that produced during physical activity.
>
> NIVEA Stress Protect Roll-On is scientifically proven to protect against emotional sweating.

They claim their products have technologies proven to be more effective against stress sweat. I'm skeptical of this.

Is there any difference between sweat caused by heat or exercise and sweat caused by emotional stress? If so, are there any substances shown to work better against emotional sweat?

Comment: http://www.nydailynews.com/life-style/health/stress-sweat-study-article-1.1496501, http://www.plosone.org/article/info%3Adoi%2F10.1371%2Fjournal.pone.0077144

Comment: @Articuno: Is that an answer?

Comment: Nope, just relevant transient information. I think they could be used in a good answer, though.

Comment: "They claim their products have technologies proven to be more effective against stress sweat." -- they don't claim that in the quote. They only claim effectiveness, not increased (or specific) effectiveness.